# Admob is overlapping the Layout Content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I created an app and put Admob inside it. But the admob is overlapping the content in my relative layout (I think So).

My XML code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_frag"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->
    <com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srl_direction="both">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>

    </com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>

    <com.exfileexplorer.filemanager.ui.views.FastScroller
        android:id="@+id/fastscroll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nofilelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_white_36dp"/>

        <TextView
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:id="@+id/nofiletext"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/nofiles"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer" />
</FrameLayout>
```

ScreenShot
[image]
I am attaching a screenshot how it looks like. As per the admob policy its clearly unethical. How to place the ad code in between them without violating ad policy.

Comment: Use `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` for AdView.

Comment: It bring ad to the bottom. I want ad at the same place without overlapping the content.  In the screenshot above, under the ad there are some text. If there is no ad, we can view the text.. Hope you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

put the admob block inside the relative layout and add this     android:layout_below="@id/nofiletext" to the admob block, like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer" 
    android:layout_below="@id/nofiletext"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, so, try add this android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in the first version of your code, how it was before